# Are “estrangeirismos” and “palavras-estrangeiras” best as separate tags or as synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We currently have:

- [11 questions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrangeiras) tagged [palavras-estrangeiras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrangeiras)
- [4 questions](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos) tagged [estrangeirismos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos)

Are those two completely differently things, somewhat overlapping things, or synonymous things?

One argument that they are different is that an estrangeirismo is a loanword that has been adopted into Portuguese and can be found in a Portuguese dictionary, whereas palavras estrangeiras are foreign terms which are not found there.

The two tag wiki excerpts did not completely clarify this for me because
the tag excerpt for [palavras-estrageiras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrageiras) currently reads:

> - Estrangeirismo é o processo que introduz palavras vindas de outros idiomas na língua portuguesa. De acordo com o idioma de origem, as palavras recebem nomes específicos, tais como anglicismo (do inglês), galicismo (do francês), etc.

And the tag excerpt for [estrangeirismos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos) currently reads:

> - Palavras provenientes de outros idiomas introduzidas, com ou sem aportuguesamento, na língua portuguesa.

If we mean to keep these two tags separate, could the two tag wiki excerpts be made clearer about which is which? Right now they seem to refer to each other.

---

## Resolution

Based on community input, I have merged [palavras-estrageiras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrageiras)  into [estrangeirismos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos). Thanks for speaking up.

Comment: I recommend you read my awnser (shame I only read this question now), because I believe you made the wrong decision, as palavras-estrangeiras are NOT estrangeirismos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory they are different things.
But in practice, it seems they are not.

I think the tag [palavras-estrangeiras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrangeiras) should be removed; all its questions seem to belong to either [estrangeirismos](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estrangeirismos) or [tradução](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Comment: Maybe you are right...

Answer (score 3):

I think tags are only as useful as the people using them, or something like that. Anyway, if people are prone to mistag questions with [palavras-estrangeiras](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/palavras-estrangeiras), then we should get rid of it.

(I'm also wondering what kind of questions could be asked about foreign words that are **not** *estrangeirismos*, i.e. not adopted into the Portuguese language, that are still questions about the Portuguese language...)

My verdict: [bຸu້ຼrົnັiຼna໊teັຼ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/what-does-it-mean-to-burninate-a-tag)

Answer (score 1):

It should not be merged as they are different things. It's a shame I only got to read this now, and it's too late, but here's my input on this matter.

*Estrangeirismos* means that it's a word or term that was adapted into the Portuguese language, but given a spin. It's phonetically and orthographically different than the original

*Palavras-Estrangeiras* literally means "foreign words". Meaning, words that are from other languages and were incorporated without any changes, and are, while acceptable, are not Portuguese.

---

[image]

**abat-jour**, is a French word for the item in the image above. It's incorrect to say it in Portuguese, because **abajur** is used in Portuguese. It's an *Estrangeirismo*. Meaning, it's not native, but it's adapted into our language.

On the other hand, you have **ja** ("iá"), meaning *Yes* in German (Jawohl, "iávol", is the correct term but phonetically it can be used as a simple 'ya'). This is also used phonetically in Portuguese, and is simply the incorporation of a foreign word in our language, without actually adapting it. It's simply a different way of saying 'yes'.

Another example would be 'Yes'. While it does still mean yes (en) / sim (pt), it's used as an expression of joy "YES! Eu Ganhei", much more common than "Sim! Eu Ganhei".

Both Ya and Yes are foreign words, adapted into verbal culture. Abajur is a 'estrangeirismo'. This proves they are different things.

Comment: Oak, [Jawohl](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Jawohl) is different from [Ja](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=Ja). Ja means simply yes, but Jawohl has a  further nuance of "[an emphatic yes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jawohl)".

Comment: It's never too late; we can always change whatever decision we reached.